# Replacing a files into multiple folders/subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way in command prompt to take files and replace it into another folder and it's sub directories based on it's name?

I have an images in my folder and i have folder have sub directories that have the same name of images, what i want to do i need to replace the image in the sub directories base on the image in my main folder.

Comment: It's very likely that a _Google_ search will yield the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Please post the batch code you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for other similar questions and I found a few topics that might interest you.

1. [Batch file to move files based on name w/o creating new folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035754/batch-file-to-move-files-based-on-name-w-o-creating-new-folders)
2. [Batch Create a Folder Based on Filename, and Move Multiple Related
   Files to The Created Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921039/batch-create-a-folder-based-on-filename-and-move-multiple-related-files-to-the)

If you post the code you have already tried, it may be possible to fix any issues you are having.